# Needs, Get and <<

Tags: packages

I think I read somewhere that `Needs` is the recommended way to import dependencies, but I usually see `<<` used in examples. The documentation seems to be saying that `<<` is just alternative syntax for `Get`. The documentation for `Needs` says that it calls `Get`, but does not explicitly say whether or not it does anything else and what that might be. Is there a more more precise statement of the relation between these somewhere?

Comment: `Get` and `<<` are the same thing as far as I know. `Needs` calls `Get` only if the package was not loaded already. If the package is already loaded, then `Needs` is smart enough to know this and will not reload it. Sometimes reloading the same package again might cause a problem (that is what I read somewhere). Not sure of why and how. So, it is better to use `Needs` I would think, just in case the package itself was not designed to be aware of itself being loaded before, or it assumed it was not loaded. I think a well designed package should not cause a problem with multiple `Get`.

Comment: I seem to remember learning somewhere that `Needs` will let *Mathematica* know the names that are publicly declared in the package (typically by means of `::usage` message definitions), even though their definitions are not yet available. Is this incorrect?